# Can't get additionalSearchFields to work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

```
jsonStoreInit = function(pSuccess, pFailure){
    collections={};
    collections['objects'] = {};

    var options = {};
    options.localKeyGen = false;
    options.clear = false;
    options.username = app.username;
    options.password = app.password;
    options.additionalSearchFields = {key: 'string'};

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
    .then(pSuccess)
    .fail(pFailure);
};


putObject = function(pObject) {
    var keyValue = pObject.getKey();
    var object = {myObject : pObject.getKey()};
    var options = {}; 
    //options.additionalSearchFields = {key : keyValue};

    WL.JSONStore.get("objects")
    .add(object, options);
};
```

I'm on WL 6.0 FP 1
In the code sample above jsonStoreInit is what I use to init my store including the options.additionalSearchFields.

When I come to add the objects in the putObject funciton it works fine with the additionalSearchFields commented out, but when I uncomment it to add the additional fields I get an error

```
[wl.jsonstore] {"src":"store","err":21,"msg":"INVALID_ADD_INDEX_KEY","col":"objects","usr":"xxxx","doc":{},"res":{}}
```

When I look this error message up all I get is

```
21 INVALID_ADD_INDEX_KEY
Problem with additional search fields.
```

Which I had kinda figured ... can anyone provide any help on this ...
I don't need to you fix my code but if you could point me to a working example that would be excellent.

Many thanks, ownimage

Comment: Solved it ... I was putting the additonalSearchFields in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The person that asked the question solved it, but I'm leaving this answer in case someone is wondering how to pass data that uses additionalSearchFields.

Example:

```
var data = {hello: 'world'};
WL.JSONStore.get('collection').add(data, {additionalSearchFields: {key: 'value'}})
```

The example assumes the collection was created with a search field for `hello` as `string` and an additional search field for `key` as `string`. It also assumes there's a collection initialized called `collection`.